# How do I push up my changes to a master git organization from a forked copy dev branch?

Tags: git

How do I push up my changes to a master git organization from a forked copy dev branch?

Comment: See [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Comment: You need to create a pull request in the master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly. You would have to push your changes to your forked repository, then make a pull request to the master repository, and the owner of the of the master repository has to accept your changes.